# Decoding SVG image to bitmap

Tags: android, svg, bitmap

I am using Android Studio to convert my SVG image to XML file . It works fine when I try to access it using R.drawable.svgimage but now I need to decode that image to bitmap.

I tried the following. It returns null for the bitmap.

```
mResId = R.drawable.svgimage
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            mContext.getResources(), mResId, options);
```

Comment: SVG files *are* XML files. Android Studio is not converting anything.  Android does not support SVG files natively.  You will need to use one of the external libraries to do anything with them.  However, If you SVG files are simple enough, you might be able to convert them to VectorDrawables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the package `androidx.core.graphics.drawable` there is a function [Drawable.toBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/graphics/drawable/package-summary#(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable).toBitmap(kotlin.Int,%20kotlin.Int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config))

```
val yourBitmap = getDrawable(R.drawable.svgimage)!!.toBitmap(width, height)
```

Answer (score 22):

The following code will works perfectly I have used it:
  Here `R.drawable.ic_airport` is my svg image stored in drawable folder.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
     private static Bitmap getBitmap(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: 1");
        return bitmap;
    }

      private static Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, int drawableId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getBitmap: 2");
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId);
        if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), drawableId);
        } else if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable) {
            return getBitmap((VectorDrawable) drawable);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type");
        }
    }

       Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_airport);
```

Comment: Somebody please provide an explanation of setting bounds only for right and bottom. Why not for all? Why set it at all?

Comment: And why @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)? Does it mean that it's not going to work on devices with another api level?

Comment: As you can see there are two methods, the first method  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) is for Target lollipop onwards and the other is for rest target versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this library [SVG Android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android) and use it this way:

```
SVG svg = new SVGBuilder()
            .readFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.someSvgResource) // if svg in res/raw
            .readFromAsset(getAssets(), "somePicture.svg")           // if svg in assets
            // .setWhiteMode(true) // draw fills in white, doesn't draw strokes
            // .setColorSwap(0xFF008800, 0xFF33AAFF) // swap a single colour
            // .setColorFilter(filter) // run through a colour filter
            // .set[Stroke|Fill]ColorFilter(filter) // apply a colour filter to only the stroke or fill
            .build();
```

After that, convert the SVG into a Drawable:

```
// Draw onto a canvas
canvas.drawPicture(svg.getPicture());

// Turn into a drawable
Drawable drawable = svg.createDrawable();
```

and then, the drawable into a bitmap:

```
Bitmap bitmapsvg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),drawable);
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do it without using external library?

Comment: apparently even google build a library time ago: https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/ and continues over: https://github.com/pents90/svg-android but looks like, yes, you need it.

Comment: Now that Android studio supports conversion to SVG in 1.4 build . http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/09/android-studio-14.html .         I hope Google tells us how to get a bitmap out of it without an external library.

Answer (score 1):

first create xml file from svg file for that

1. right click on drawable
2. new -> vector asset
3. select svg file and create xml file

after that use that xml file like below

```
val bitmap = getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_black_camel)!!.toBitmap(width, height)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable):

```
VectorDrawable vd = (VectorDrawable) context.getDrawable( R.drawable.ic_00 );
```

2) Calculate bitmap ratio and size by vd.getIntrinsicWidth(); and vd.getIntrinsicHeight();.

3) Create canvas with the bitmap.

4) Use vd.setBounds( left, top, right, bottom ); as destination rectangle

5) Finally draw:

```
vd.draw( canvas );
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.android);
PictureDrawable pictureDrawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), pictureDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: Where are SVG and SVGParser from?