# BitmapFactory.decodeResources returns a null object

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I am trying to draw an icon under a row of a RecyclerView when it is swiped, similar to the Gmail or Inbox app. I have the color implemented, but the Bitmap that I am trying to draw is evading me. I am using the delete icon from the https://material.io/icons/ website. I downloaded it as an SVG and imported it to my drawables folder as an XML file. My code is as follows:

```
private Paint p = new Paint();
private ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback ithSC = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        fileData.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView rv, RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, float dx, float dy, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_delete);
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

            // this gets the RecyclerView row from the ViewHolder
            View itemView = vh.itemView;

            // p is a Paint object, setting the color
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            c.drawRect(dx, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom(), p);

            super.onChildDraw(c, rv, vh, dx,dy, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }
};
```

When I run the app, the logcat has the message:

```
D/skia: ---- fAsset->read(8192) returned 0
D/skia: --- SkAndroidCodec::NewFromStream returned null
```

Why is the BitmapFactory.decodeResource() call returning a null object and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:

I have tried a few other things, here is my updated code. One of the big changes is that the icon is a PNG not an XML

```
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView rv, RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh, float dx, float dy, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {

            // this gets the RecyclerView row from the ViewHolder
            View itemView = vh.itemView;

            // get the width and height
            float height = itemView.getHeight();
            float width = height/3;

            // p is a Paint object, setting the color
            p.setColor(Color.RED);
            c.drawRect(dx, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom(), p);

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_delete);
            RectF destination = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width , (float) itemView.getTop() + width, (float) itemView.getRight() - width, (float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
            c.drawBitmap(b, null, destination, p);

            super.onChildDraw(c, rv, vh, dx,dy, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
        }
    }
};
```

Here is the error I am still getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `Thanks in advance`. No. That is not what we want.

Comment: make your life simple download in png format, for different screens for svg  [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716570/decoding-svg-image-to-bitmap)

Comment: "imported it to my drawables folder as an XML file" -- what does this mean, exactly? If you mean that you imported it as a vector drawable, and you have the XML file for that as a resource, I don't think that you can use `BitmapFactory` to load it in.

Comment: @CommonsWare File > New > Vector Asset. So yes, it is a vector drawable. If I cannot use BitmapFactory, what should I use?

Comment: Well, you do not seem to be using it, unless I am missing something in your code. So, you might just get rid of that line. Assuming that you do need it, use `getDrawable()` on a `Resources` object.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that as well, earlier before I asked this question. I will try that again and post the log when I have time. Also, I tried importing it as an image asset instead, and get the following error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gus.voicerecorder/com.gus.voicerecorder.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Also, I thought that `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name)` was deprecated as of API 22

Comment: Your `Context` was `null` on which you called `getResources()`. There are a few `getDrawable()` methods, and not all are deprecated.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah I hadn't included it in the code because every time it runs it would immediately crash. When I just tried to define the Bitmap object it would at least print a different message to the logcat. Also, I updated the question with the code/use of the Bitmap, if you could take a look at it I would appreciate it